# Snake program with list of lists doesn't always work

Tags: python, list, image, matrix, pixel

here is my code:

```
class Colors:
    orange = (255, 128, 0)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    gray = (128, 128, 128)
    green = (0, 255, 0)

def move(l: list[list], c: str):
    pass

def generate_snake(start_img: str, position: list[int, int], commands: str, out_img: str) -> int:
    dimension = 1
    moves = commands.split()
    position = list(reversed(position))
    history = []
    l = images.load(start_img)
    posX, posY = position

    for i, move in enumerate(moves):
        if l[posX][posY] == Colors.orange:
            dimension += 1
        elif l[posX][posY] in [Colors.green, Colors.red] or i == len(moves)-1:
            break
        l[posX][posY] = Colors.gray
        if move == "E":
            posY += 1
        elif move == "N":
            posX -= 1
        elif move == "NE":
            posX -= 1
            posY += 1
        elif move == "NW":
            posX, posY = posX-1, posY-1
        elif move == "S":
            posX += 1
        elif move == "SE":
            posX += 1
            posY += 1
        elif move == "SW":
            posX += 1
            posY -= 1
        elif move == "W":
            posY -= 1
        history.append([posX,posY])

    

    history.reverse()
    for i in range(1,dimension):
        l[history[i][0]][history[i][1]] = Colors.green


    images.save(l,out_img)
    return dimension

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_snake("./data/input_04.png", [19, 35], "S S S S W W W W N N N N N N E E E E E E E N E S S S E E E E S E S E S E S E S E N N N N N N N E N E E N E N N E N E N E N E N E N N W N W N W N W W W N W N W N W N W W W N N N N E N N E N E E E E NE NE NE NE S NW SW NE NE S SE S E W S W N E NW SE S NW NW NE SE NE S S E SW W NE NE S W NW SE S S SE NE N SW SW NW NW S S N SE SW E SE SW NW NW SW SW NE W W N SE SW S S SW S SW S S S W S E N NW NW SW S NE S SW SE NE S NW W NE W N S S SW NE SW NE SW SW NE W SW SE E W N SW W NE SE SE S W SE NW NW N E NE SW NW SW W NE NW NW NE S N E NE NE N N E E S NW SW NW E NW NE S E SW N W NE S NW NE N N N N NW SW S SW NW SW SW W NW SW SW E SE W W W NE SE SE S E S SE E W NW SE NE S SW E NW NW S SE S N W NE NW SW S E S E S NW SW S E S NW N SW N W W NE E E N N E E S W NE SE NW E SW S SW N W S S NE NW SW NE NE N W S SE SE S SE S W N S N N NW NW NW S SE S S S SW E W NE NE NW SW W N NW W NW W S N N NE NE S S W SW S N E S NW SW N", "test_output.png")
```

I'm trying to make a snake game that function through list of lists that represent pixels of an image. The parameters are the initial field of game, with fruits and obstacle, the initial position of the snake in x, y coords in the matrix, the list of moves that the snake will do unless stopped before because of a red obstacle, and the position of the output image, I also have a class for simplifying colouring the matrix.
The program only works with certain set of parameters but not for others, I have a list of starting images, moves and expected output that my script should follow, but it only does right like 4 test over 13.
Here is the starting image of the code pasted above:
[image: input04.png]

Here is the expected output of my program: [image: expected_end_4.png]

And finally what my program produces: [image: test_output.png]

As you can see my snake should stop where the expected does, but instead it goes forward, don't really know why, because in this case the program should stop at the end of the moves because there is no red obstacle nor it walk over himself.

P.S.: I cannot use any other library except the images one for loading and saving images.

Comment: It might be better to put the code here rather than a link - it looks like you move the snake, checking for red or snake(green) but only colour the green pixels AFTER moving the snake.

Comment: @doctorlove I've added here the code, btw, when should I colour the green pixels?

Comment: So, you mean that you run the code 13 times, out of the 13 times, 4 times the expected output comes out in test_output, and 9 times test_output produced the wrong result (the third image)?

Comment: @Joshua no I meant that over 13 different tests, only 4 times it produces the right output.

Comment: Set l[posX][posY] to Colors.green just before you append to the history? Nothing will go green until you hit the second loop at the moment.